# In-app purchases are lost after uninstall on "managed" purchase type

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have read other threads here and they say that In-app purchases are stored as long as "managed" purchase type is chosen when in-app billing is set up. Managed means that when the app is reinstalled, it can ask the in-app billing service which items this particular user has already purchased. I have set up "managed" purchase type in all my apps with In-app billing. The purchases are still lost when the apps are uninstalled and then installed again. I tested with a test account as a alpha tester. The customers say the same thing.

Why does this happen? Do I really need to use a backupAgentHelper to solve this? Shouldn't this be solved by Google when I choose "managed" purchase type?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you can query the in-app billing service to get the items a user has purchases, as long as you haven't 'consumed' the item. As soon as you consume the purchase, you can no longer query the in-app billing service to get that item. Are you making a call that looks something like this?

```
iabGooglePlayHelper.mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseToken);
```

If so, then you're consuming it. If that is not the case, then it may be with how you're querying the in-app billing service. Can you pose that code if you believe it to be the problem?

Comment: I am only calling consumeRequest() while testing, so it can not be due to this. I believe it is because of how I query the in app billing service. 
Here is a link to the essential part of my code (too big to post here) :http://www.mobile-visuals.com/inapp.txt

Comment: I updated to IAP5 with the latest code from Google, but it is the same issue.

Comment: So there is no solution to this, it should not be possible for the customer to keep their purchase after reinstalling?

Comment: It is very frustrating that customers keep complaining about this and I can not to do anything about it! Is there a basic problem with Google's "in app payment" solution?

Comment: I am considering to stop using Google's "in app payment" in new apps if there is no solution to this.