# Android In-app billing upgrade does not work

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Customers sometimes report that they don't get the In-app billing (IAB) upgrade to full version, eventhough the apps are carefully tested on our test devices. We use managed IAB in 3 apps. We test through alpha testing and we have not found any problems with upgrading. 2 of the apps have IAB version 3 and 1 have IAB version 5. It is the same problem. The apps are developed according to IAB guidelines.

Why does this happen? Is there some problem with Google's servers, which causes these IAB errors, which prevents some customers from getting the upgrade? Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

This is a very serious issue for my company, since it results in bad reviews and lower rankings for the IAB apps. We can not use IAB in the upcoming apps, since it seems to be too unreliable. It is also very annoying that IAB seems to be much more reliable on iOS. These are 2 other issues with IAB, which we still haven't found any solution to:

[Consume purchase for In-app billing does not work on Android 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481125/consume-purchase-for-in-app-billing-does-not-work-on-android-6)

[In-app purchases are lost after uninstall on "managed" purchase type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460219/in-app-purchases-are-lost-after-uninstall-on-managed-purchase-type)

Here are the statistics about this issue:

app 1: 1215 sold upgrades, 2 complaints from customers who did not get the upgrade

app 2: 94 sold upgrades, 2 complaints from customers who did not get the upgrade

app 3: 122 sold upgrades, 4 complaints from customers who did not get the upgrade

There could be more customers, who did not get the upgrade. The statistics are only for those who complained. ﻿

Comment: I have confirmed that other Android developers have the same issue. 0,5% of all In-app purchases just get lost. Another developer has researched this and come to these conclusions: 1) There are issues with GPS caching of Play servers response, which causes IAB to return outdated response.
2) There are issues with multi-account if the user has more than one account configured in Google Play. One account used for purchase has to be set as default at least once. This is probably a common cause of issues when the user is reinstalling an app or installing an app on  or a secondary device.

Comment: In my products also have this problem. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got solved somewhere in the later versions of the In-app billing API, so this is no longer a problem.